# Django Allauth: How to customize confirmation email subject?

Tags: python, django, django-allauth

I was able to customize the confirmation email HTML template by adding this file into the templates folder:

```
templates/account/email/email_confirmation_signup_message.html
```

Now I'm trying to customize the subject of the email by adding the text I want inside this file:

```
templates/account/email/email_confirmation_signup_subject.txt
```

But it doesn't seem to do anything, I still get the default subject all the time.

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Many thanks!

Comment: maybe try clearing you browser cache?

Comment: @AryanMishra I tried but didnt do anything, I dont think that the browser cache affects email subjects.

Comment: did you delete the email_confirmation_signup_message.html file ? and also did you update the template name in your django app to have the txt file?

Answer (score 2):

You have to add this two files...
first:
account/email/email_confirmation_signup_message.html

```
{% include "account/email/email_confirmation_message.html" %}
```

second:

account/email/email_confirmation_message.html

```
The template that you want.
```

and finally delete the two .txt file:
account/email/email_confirmation_signup_message.txt
account/email/email_confirmation_message.txt

pd: if you copy the folder template/account from your virtual enviroment you have to delete the files over there as well.

Comment: Thanks a lot, spent quite some time, until your answer completely fixed my issue!

Answer (score 1):

Change file name to this:-
`templates/account/email/email_confirmation_subject.txt`
and inside write

```
{% load i18n %}
{% autoescape off %}
{% blocktrans %}Please Confirm Your E-mail Address or do whatever..{% endblocktrans %}
{% endautoescape %}
```

Comment: I tried both email_confirmation_subject.txt and email_confirmation_signup_subject.txt and I keep getting the same default subject

Comment: On original github someone also reported this check if this can help ---- https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth/issues/2625

Answer (score 1):

1. For me the default behavior was to have the template in the the project folder and not in the particular apps directory `api_project/templates/account/email/email_confirmation_subject.txt`!
2. For anybody that might be here just because [example.com] still appears at the subject even when they customized successfully the `templates/account/email/email_confirmation_subject.txt` a variable that you need to configure and it's not quit obvious it's `ACCOUNT_EMAIL_SUBJECT_PREFIX = '[example.com]'`

Answer (score 0):

Do in this way...

- install django-mail-templated
- base template file code...

```
{{ TAG_START_SUBJECT }}
{% autoescape off %}
{% block subject %}
{% endblock %}
{% endautoescape %}
{{ TAG_END_SUBJECT }}
```

- main template file code...

```
{% block subject %}
Hello User..
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the problem comes with your urls.py file
You need to indicate here the file you use to customize the subject of your email.

```
PasswordResetView.as_view(template_name='email_confirmation_signup_message.html', subject_template_name='email_confirmation_signup_subject.txt')
```